# using new URL to access web app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, domain

We are switching internet domains at work, but the old domain is not going away, given the legacy support required (AD domain is also not changing).  I have a small (1 SP server, 1 SQL server) SP2013 SP1 farm which I would like to have people access with the new domain. So *e.g.* the SP web app currently lives at `portal.mycompany.com` and I want people to access it at `newportal.newcompany.com`. It looked like Alternative Access Mappings would be the ticket but I am not seeing how to utilize that, if it is even possible.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, You have to Create New DNS record(newportal.newcompany.com) pointing to your SP server.

Then, You have to Update the AAM settings and add the new url their.

Also make sure the IIS bindings also updated(if any).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Exactly what are the steps needed on the AAM page? My attempts here haven't worked.

Comment: what steps you performed? you want old URL also their?

Comment: I have created the new DNS record.  I have tried changing both the Internal URL and Public URL to newportal.newcompany.com, (as well as adding an Internal URL), but nothing I do works (other than causing the web app to temporarily stop working :). Is there some set of steps to take you can point me to?

Comment: For me, it is simple...simply exchange the old url with new...Updating the Public URLS....what error you get? also did you change the Domain for the Services account as well?

Comment: I get error 404 when I attempt to go to http://newportal.newcompany.com.  On the AAM page for my web app (Alternative Access Mapping Collection:) 'SharePoint - portal.mycompany.com80' I have 1 mapping, with Internal URL = ``http://newportal.newcompany.com``; Zone = Default; Public URL for Zone = ``http://newportal.newcompany.com``.  I did not change any domain for the Services account - where do I do that in Central Admin?

Comment: My DNS admins have not yet rolled out record updates for newcompany.com - I just have newportal.newcompany.com set in the hosts file on my PC and on the SP sever.  Could this be causing problems in any way?

Comment: 404 is not the DNS issue rather it is sharepoint issue, make sure the content database attached.

Comment: The content database is indeed attached.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the precise instructions.  (Your answer was technically correct but lacked detail.)  
- Navigate to Alternate Access Mappings page; make sure the desired 'Alternate Access Mapping Collection' is selected in the drop-down, on the right side of the page  
- Click 'Edit Public URLs'  
- Add the desired alias in the 'Intranet' field (the 'Default' field should already contain the existing default URL); Click Save  
- Open IIS on the SP server; right-click on the site containing the desired web app and select 'Edit Bindings...'  
- Add new hostname which was added on the AAM page

Comment: Glad You fix it. Sorry, i thought you are selecting the desired web app. I should mentioned that. I will update the anwser.